# Can I get a receipt as an eBay buyer?

Tags: ebay

Is there a way to download and print a receipt for a purchase I made on eBay using a credit card (off PayPal)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your eBay dashboard and under `Purchase History` find the order in question and from the `+` dropdown menu click on `Show Shipping Details`.

You can always, also refer to your payment in the PayPal dashboard.

Comment: It doesn't contain an official receipt, maybe sort of invoice. As stated in my question, the purchase was made directly from eBay to the credit-card, without PayPal.